# How to know the type of file in IOS

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5

I have a file downloaded in the document folder of my ipad application. I want to know  the type of file irrespective of its extension. In short i want to get something similar to the result of the "file" command as shown below, with my ios code. Any help?
[image]

Comment: http://www.darwinsys.com/file/

Comment: i am looking to use without running the shell script, via using inbuilt classes  like NSDirectory etc...

Comment: https://github.com/aidansteele/MagicKit

Comment: The magic occurs mostly in src/magic.c.